# Android Studio - Native method not found - Include .so file, missing jni function option

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am working on a Android fingerprint project with JNI. I have some source of the project, but i only have .so file and the .java file of the source. how to resolve missing jni function option and how to use native method

[image]

Comment: i got this answer....i explain when call this path then use actual package path..like my project path is com.aadhar.startek.fm220 then create java class which name is tstlib..i use difference path when error is occur...like my path is com.ashishnewproj.aadhar.startek.fm220....so every time is error is occur.....so keep on mind when use .so file then notice allready is use sdk path  will use actual sdk path....not change manually....

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

i got this answer....i explain when call this path then use actual package path..like my project path is com.aadhar.startek.fm220 then create java class which name is tstlib..i use difference path when error is occur...like my path is com.ashishnewproj.aadhar.startek.fm220....so every time is error is occur.....so keep on mind when use .so file then notice allready is use sdk path will use actual sdk path....not change manually....